# Get a node's attribute depending on another attribute and its parents attribute using Xpath in R

Tags: r, xml, xpath

I have xml document that has following structure and I want to select valueStart and valueEnd attribute values depending on Balance attribute bsdate value and BalanceRow attribute rowNum value. For instance:

- bsdate = '2013' and rowNum = '200' valueStart should be '3000' and valueEnd - '4000'
- bsdate = '2014' and rowNum = '102' valueStart should be '5500' and valueEnd - '6500'

Is it possible to do in R? I spent whole day searching for answer, but wasn't able to find it

```
    <Root
    xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/">
    <Balance bsdate = '2013' bsregdate = '2014.04.01'>
        <BalanceRows type = 'B' rowNum = '100' valueStart = '1000' valueEnd = '2000'></BalanceRows>
        <BalanceRows type = 'B' rowNum = '101' valueStart = '3000' valueEnd = '4000'></BalanceRows>
        <BalanceRows type = 'B' rowNum = '102' valueStart = '5000' valueEnd = '6000'></BalanceRows>
        <BalanceRows type = 'P' rowNum = '200' valueStart = '7000' valueEnd = '8000'></BalanceRows>
        <BalanceRows type = 'P' rowNum = '201' valueStart = '9000' valueEnd = '10000'></BalanceRows>
    </Balance>
    <Balance bsdate = '2014' bsregdate = '2015.04.02'>
        <BalanceRows type = 'B' rowNum = '100' valueStart = '1500' valueEnd = '2500' ></BalanceRows>
        <BalanceRows type = 'B' rowNum = '101' valueStart = '3500' valueEnd = '4500'></BalanceRows>
        <BalanceRows type = 'B' rowNum = '102' valueStart = '5500' valueEnd = '6500'></BalanceRows>
        <BalanceRows type = 'P' rowNum = '200' valueStart = '7500' valueEnd = '8500'></BalanceRows>
        <BalanceRows type = 'P' rowNum = '201' valueStart = '9500' valueEnd = '15000'></BalanceRows>
    </Balance>
</Root>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uisng the test data

```
library(xml2)
xx <- read_xml("<Root xmlns:a=\"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/\">
  <Balance bsdate = '2013' bsregdate = '2014.04.01'>
  <BalanceRows type = 'B' rowNum = '100' valueStart = '1000' valueEnd = '2000'></BalanceRows>
  <BalanceRows type = 'B' rowNum = '101' valueStart = '3000' valueEnd = '4000'></BalanceRows>
  <BalanceRows type = 'B' rowNum = '102' valueStart = '5000' valueEnd = '6000'></BalanceRows>
  <BalanceRows type = 'P' rowNum = '200' valueStart = '7000' valueEnd = '8000'></BalanceRows>
  <BalanceRows type = 'P' rowNum = '201' valueStart = '9000' valueEnd = '10000'></BalanceRows>
  </Balance>
  <Balance bsdate = '2014' bsregdate = '2015.04.02'>
  <BalanceRows type = 'B' rowNum = '100' valueStart = '1500' valueEnd = '2500' ></BalanceRows>
  <BalanceRows type = 'B' rowNum = '101' valueStart = '3500' valueEnd = '4500'></BalanceRows>
  <BalanceRows type = 'B' rowNum = '102' valueStart = '5500' valueEnd = '6500'></BalanceRows>
  <BalanceRows type = 'P' rowNum = '200' valueStart = '7500' valueEnd = '8500'></BalanceRows>
  <BalanceRows type = 'P' rowNum = '201' valueStart = '9500' valueEnd = '15000'></BalanceRows>
  </Balance>
  </Root>")
```

You can grab the attribites of the matching rows with

```
xml_attrs(xml_find_all(xx, "//Balance[@bsdate = '2014']/BalanceRows[@rowNum='200']"))
# [[1]]
#       type     rowNum valueStart   valueEnd 
#       "P"      "200"     "7500"     "8500
```